# Creating PayPal Invoice or payment link with Python

Tags: python, paypal

Help me to issue a simple invoice for a client through the python language. We need a simple form of "request for money", so to speak

I was told that the sdk is not suitable for my purpose. I started using the Invoice API. Was able to get access_token. But I can't solve the following tasks:

1.Generate and send an invoice for a certain amount to the client.
2.Perform a check. Find out if the customer has paid the invoice.

If you help me and share the lines of code, I will be very grateful. I read the API documentation as much as I can, but I couldn't understand everything. I thank you in advance and apologize for my English, it is not my native language.

```
import requests

resp = requests.post(
    url="https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token",
    auth=("my_client_id", "my_secret"),
    data=b"grant_type=client_credentials",
    headers={
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Language": "en_US",
    },
)
resp.raise_for_status()

access_token = resp.json()['access_token']
# =======================================
r = requests.post(url="https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/invoicing/invoices",
data=b'{"intent": "CAPTURE","items": {"name": "podpiska", "description": "thats test desc for test purchase", "quantity": "1", "unit_amount": {"currency": "USD", "value": "100.00"}}}',
                  headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": f"Bearer {access_token}",})

print(r.status_code, r.json())
```

This is what my code looks like now. Before "= = = = = = " the working part of the code where I get access_token, after this line my attempts to create an invoice

Comment: That data payload doesn't make sense, it's for a v2 orders checkout, you need an invoice create payload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a correct data payload for your invoice create call. Try something based on the following...

```py
data='''{
  "detail": {
    "reference": "deal-ref",
    "invoice_date": "2020-11-12",
    "currency_code": "USD",
    "note": "Thank you for your business.",
    "term": "No refunds after 30 days.",
    "memo": "This is a long contract",
    "payment_term": {
      "term_type": "NET_10",
      "due_date": "2020-11-22"
    }
  },
  "invoicer": {
    "name": {
      "given_name": "David",
      "surname": "Larusso"
    },
    "address": {
      "address_line_1": "1234 First Street",
      "address_line_2": "337673 Hillside Court",
      "admin_area_2": "Anytown",
      "admin_area_1": "CA",
      "postal_code": "98765",
      "country_code": "US"
    },
    "email_address": "EMAIL_OF_RECEIVER @ SOMEWHERE.COM",
    "phones": [
      {
        "country_code": "001",
        "national_number": "4085551234",
        "phone_type": "MOBILE"
      }
    ],
    "website": "www.test.com",
    "tax_id": "ABcNkWSfb5ICTt73nD3QON1fnnpgNKBy- Jb5SeuGj185MNNw6g",
    "logo_url": "https://example.com/logo.PNG",
    "additional_notes": "2-4"
  },
  "primary_recipients": [
    {
      "billing_info": {
        "name": {
          "given_name": "Stephanie",
          "surname": "Meyers"
        },
        "address": {
          "address_line_1": "1234 Main Street",
          "admin_area_2": "Anytown",
          "admin_area_1": "CA",
          "postal_code": "98765",
          "country_code": "US"
        },
        "email_address": "PERSON_TO_SEND_INVOICE_TO @ SOMEWHERE.COM",
        "phones": [
          {
            "country_code": "001",
            "national_number": "4884551234",
            "phone_type": "HOME"
          }
        ],
        "additional_info_value": "add-info"
      },
      "shipping_info": {
        "name": {
          "given_name": "Stephanie",
          "surname": "Meyers"
        },
        "address": {
          "address_line_1": "1234 Main Street",
          "admin_area_2": "Anytown",
          "admin_area_1": "CA",
          "postal_code": "98765",
          "country_code": "US"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "items": [
    {
      "name": "Yoga Mat",
      "description": "Elastic mat to practice yoga.",
      "quantity": "1",
      "unit_amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "50.00"
      },
      "tax": {
        "name": "Sales Tax",
        "percent": "7.25"
      },
      "discount": {
        "percent": "5"
      },
      "unit_of_measure": "QUANTITY"
    },
    {
      "name": "Yoga t-shirt",
      "quantity": "1",
      "unit_amount": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "10.00"
      },
      "tax": {
        "name": "Sales Tax",
        "percent": "7.25"
      },
      "discount": {
        "amount": {
          "currency_code": "USD",
          "value": "5.00"
        }
      },
      "unit_of_measure": "QUANTITY"
    }
  ],
  "configuration": {
    "partial_payment": {
      "allow_partial_payment": true,
      "minimum_amount_due": {
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "value": "20.00"
      }
    },
    "allow_tip": true,
    "tax_calculated_after_discount": true,
    "tax_inclusive": false,
    "template_id": ""
  },
  "amount": {
    "breakdown": {
      "custom": {
        "label": "Packing Charges",
        "amount": {
          "currency_code": "USD",
          "value": "10.00"
        }
      },
      "shipping": {
        "amount": {
          "currency_code": "USD",
          "value": "10.00"
        },
        "tax": {
          "name": "Sales Tax",
          "percent": "7.25"
        }
      },
      "discount": {
        "invoice_discount": {
          "percent": "5"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'''
```

And if you still have issues, your question should include the unexpected output or error you are receiving when run.